# How to keep the previous version of an entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to keep the previous version of an entity called *Item*. When I update it, I would create a new entity with the same id but with a new version number. I try to use a *listener* but in this way I can't persist a new Item in the *preUpdate* method (infinite loop).

```
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof Item) {

        // Create a new version of the current item
        $item = new Item();
        $item->setId(($entity->getId());
        $item->setVersion($entity->getVersion() + 1);
        $item->setSubject($entity->getSubject());
        $item->setDetail($entity->getDetail());
        $item->setPriority($entity->getPriority());
        $item->setStatus($entity->getStatus());
        $item->setPlannedAt($entity->getPlannedAt());
        $item->setDueAt($entity->getDueAt());
        $item->setValidationToken($entity->getValidationToken());
        $item->setType($entity->getType());

        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

I thought to use an item Manager with an update method but I don't know if it's the best way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your primary key for the item table? See if this extension would work for you: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions#versionable

Comment: My primaries keys are the id and the version. I will try this extension https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit

Comment: Interesting question, one thing I will point out is to ensure your setters insist on the correct type. Make sure setStatus casts the passed value as an integer for example (if it is one). If a null or a blank get in there then a changeset will occur, and you'll end up versioning unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I use the loggable extension of [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) provided by [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/tree/1.0.x)

Thanks [kuba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330267/kuba) and [Lee Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285809/lee-davis) for your help !